# Selenium Python- How to handle NoSuchWindowException in Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, ui-automation

I am trying to automate an application that downloads files automatically. I am using Selenium with Python. But my application crashes after some time throwing the `Aw, Snap` error and my script stops showing the error message:

> NoSuchWindowException: no such window: target window already closed

So my ideas was to restart the application by including the except statement as shown:

```
except NoSuchWindowException as ex4:
    print("Exception4 has been thrown"+str(ex4))
    driver.refresh()
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    username=driver.find_element_by_id("user")
    username.clear()
    username.send_keys("")
    password=driver.find_element_by_id("pw")
    password.clear()
    password.send_keys("")
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    login=driver.find_element_by_id("loginButton")
    login.click()
```

I have tried the following in my `except` clause but didn't work :

1. `driver.refresh()`
2. Click on back button: 
    `driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")`
3. `driver.get("URL")`
4. `driver.quit`
    This worked but when I tried to relaunch the application using `driver.get("URL")` , I got the below error:

> "error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Please suggest how I can resolve this issue. 
Below is the error image: 
[image]

Thanks

Comment: IMO its a indentation error, you haven't handled the indentation in `except` block properly.

Comment: quit will close the browser, so you will have to relaunch the browser and then do the get.

Comment: @DebanjanB: My actual code has correct indentation. I pasted the code wrong.

Comment: @saurabhbaid : I did that but when I launch it again after quitting , I get an error ,explained in point 4.

Comment: In your point 4 you are calling `get` which works on already opened session. you need to create new session like 
`WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`

Comment: @saurabhbaid: Thanks for pointing out. It is working now!!